Why the cardinal power is not a aleph when the exponent is a infinite cardinal?
I am learning the set theory with the textbook "Set theory" written by Abhijit Dasgupta. I am confused about the description outlined at page 206. The description says that when the exponent is infinite, then we can't compute the cardinal power such as 2^{\aleph_0} as an aleph even using the AC.
My question is that under the AC, since any infinite cardinal is an aleph and 2^{\aleph_0} is infinite, 2^{\aleph_0} should be \aleph_{\alpha} for some ordinal \alpha. What is wrong here?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please use MathJax.

Maybe a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20385/bound-on-the-cardinality-of-the-continuum-i-hope-not but the OP's question seems to be more about that specific phrase in the book. I will let the set theorists here decide.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. This theorem may interest you.

The emphasis is on the word "compute". You are correct that there is some ordinal $\alpha$ such that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{\alpha}$, but with ZFC alone we cannot pin down the value of $\alpha$. With forcing, you can find a model of ZFC in which $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$ (the continuum hypothesis), but also a model with $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{42}$. A more  general result ist Easton's theorem.

Thank you very much. I will learn why $2^{\aleph_0}$ could be different $\aleph_{\alpha}$ under different model following the direction you point out. Thank you again.

Why does $2^{\aleph_0}$ have to be an $\aleph_\alpha$?

@MJD $\mathsf{AC}$ is equivalent in $\mathsf{ZF}$ to all sets being well-orderable.

I think the full argument goes like this: $2^{\aleph_0}$ is well-orderable, therefore is order-isomorphic to some ordinal $\beta$. Let $\mathcal B$ be the set of ordinals equinumerous with $\beta$.  $\mathcal B$ is nonempty and therefore has a least element $\gamma$. This $\gamma$ is an $\aleph$ number because the $\aleph$s are by definition the least elements of equivalence classes such as $\mathcal B$.  Is that right?
